# Spring-Boot: How to add client authentication to TLS

Tags: spring-boot, ssl-client-authentication

I use a Spring-Boot webservice via HTTPS/TLS.
My app has a server-keypair configured in application.properties.

Now I need to upgrade it to add TLS client authentication.

Any idea how I can integrate this?